# Notebook не принимает place

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
w = Tk()
w.geometry('550x500')
note = ttk.Notebook(w)
frame = ttk.Frame(h)
note.add(n,text='okno')
note.pack()
m = Button(n,text='button')
m.place(x=30,y=30)
w.mainloop()
```

Используя в размещении кнопки button `pack` и `grid` все работает. При использовании `place` виджет не появляется. Почему так происходит и как это **исправить**?

Comment: Что такое n и h в вашем коде?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда элемент управления размещается при помощи `place`, нельзя определить, сколько места ему требуется для размещения. Из-за этого ноутбук схлопывается в минимальный размер. Чтобы не схлопывался, можно при размещении ноутбука указать, чтобы он автоматически расширялся до максимального размера внутри контейнера:

```
note.pack(expand=1, fill=BOTH)
```

А вообще `grid` и `pack` намного удобнее, чем `place` - не нужно вручную высчитывать координаты.

[image: Скриншот]